# No row was deleted/updated, error with SQL Server in C# (Winforms)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a table called `Users` with these columns

```
Username - Nvarchar(50).
Password - Nvarchar(50).
```

Now I have this data

```
UserName    Password
----------  ----------
adimin       123456
test         1234
abc           123 
abc           123
```

Now I'm trying to (**manually**) delete the `abc` users and I'm getting this error:

[image: Error]

I can add more users and update them and delete them, but I can't do anything with the `abc` users.. Why does it happen?

Comment: Can you post yout code?

Comment: Im trying to edit manually Sorry I did not mention.

Comment: What do you mean manually? Are you trying to delete them via SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Try this statement to delete these records: `delete from users where username = 'abc'`

Comment: I dont really know how its called but in C# you have 'database explorer'
and from there i go to the talbes and try to edit the users table.a

Comment: Just as a side note: I hope the password is not stored as clear text but as hash or something like that.

Comment: Well , i try to run query like @juergend said . and it works

but why in the qury it works and when im trying to do it from the table , im getting error ?

Comment: I tried this on SQL Server2008R2 and got the same issue. It seems that when you try to edit manually, you are actually having a view of the table's contents through a background 'SELECT' statement run by the engine, but can add new information. If you save and reopen the table, you won't be able to edit/delete the new information you just inputted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the records with a delete statement rather than manually in the IDE:

```
delete from users
where username = 'abc'
```

Comment: As i said , works . Thanks

I like to know why when im trying to delete or update data from the table i cant , and when im running query it works ?

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio is complaining because you didn't define a *Primary Key*. Add, for example, an identity column and it won't complain any more (since it'll know exactly which row to delete).

Ex.: `ALTER TABLE users ADD id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete all data in a table. you can use following SQL statement

**DELETE
FROM table_name**

ex :-
DELETE
FROM tblReOrderLevel